How to synthesize and manipulate polydopamine nanomembranes
I have been trying to synthesize a polydopamine nanomembrane that could filter out divalent ions. These seem to be used in various applications, but in my case, I need to filter out magnesium ions from a magnesium chloride solution. I know that ion exchange may be a more cost-effective way to do this; however, they release sodium or hydrogen ions that may contaminate the chloride ions which I require (e.g. by the formation of hydrochloric acid or table salt).
I tried to find pre-made polydopamine, but I could not find anything. I found some articles which mentioned the process and I tried to synthesize some from Dopamine hydrochloride. I do not know what went wrong, but the product I ended up with was not polydopamine. Does anyone know of a detailed procedure for its synthesis and what equipment may be necessary to create this product? I would also like to know how I may manipulate this membrane so that only divalent ions can be stopped/pass through.

More information (synthetic route you attempted), what exactly you did to verify it was the desired product, etc, might be useful for someone to pinpoint what went wrong.
